# DDR2 and DDR3 ODT and ZQ calibration

Tags: termination, ddr, ddr3, ddr2

1. Can anyone please explain what is the difference in ODT and ZQ technique used in DDR2 and DDR3??
2. Which method is very useful for DDR2 termination? whether ODT or External parallel termination??

Regards,
M.Arun kumar